# Getting argumental error for all of my keyword(s) which I want to call with Run Keywords method

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

Example

> | Run Keywords
>       | | ... | Borrower Enter employer and income information | ${filename} | ${row_num}
>       | | ... | And | Borrower enters employer phone number | ${list['employerphone']}
>       | | ... | And | Borrower Affirm Income Information

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code by formatting it as code rather than as a block quote.

Answer (score 1):

The `AND` connector between the keywords **must** be in upper case - this is how the framework distinguishes it from an argument "and", "And" and other variations.

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords

Comment: Ya after asking I checked one document . Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Your AND Operator seems to be in wrong position

```
|Run Keywords|
|...|Borrower Enter employer and income information | ${filename} | ${row_num} | And |
|...|Borrower enters employer phone number | ${list['employerphone']} | And |
|...|Borrower Affirm Income Information
```